# How come discriminant can be used to find range of a function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Find range of function $f(x)=x^2+6x-1$ for domain $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

The solution is:

Let $y=x^2+6x-1$ then $0=x^2+6x-1-y$
comparing with $0=ax^2+bx+c$ gives $a=1,b=6,c=-(1+y)$
For real $x$, $b^2-4ac \geq 0$ i.e $6^2 -(4)(1)[-(1+y)] \geq 0$
giving $y \geq -10$

Thus for real $x$ the function $f(x)=x^2+6x-1$ has range $\{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y \ge1 -10 \}$

I don't understand the technique of using discriminant to find range of function. I need assistance.

Comment: This is something of a special case, the function here being a polynomial and a quadratic polynomial at that.  The domain being real numbers $\mathbb R$ also plays an important part in the analysis.  Rather than using the "discriminant" (which is a fine technique when one understands it, as your Question illustrates), one gets to the same conclusion by completing the square.  So maybe one way to proceed is by using both methods to see that one arrives at the same solution?

Comment: Hint. Draw the graph of that parabola. Then find the   $y$ value at the lowest point.

Comment: My doubt is that, can 'x' which is supposed to represent only one value represents a whole set of values called Domain.  And also 'y' which is supposed to be the answer for x^2+6x-1, be called as range.

Comment: While $x$ might represent "only one value", in this context it is formally the *argument* of the function $f(x)$.  As $x\in \mathbb R$ varies over the whole domain, the corresponding outputs $f(x)$ will cover the *range*.  The problem asks you to determine what subset of $\mathbb R$ is that range, using the discriminant.

Comment: @hardmath- The thing that I don't understand is, how can you use discriminant to find range of a function. I see no link between range of a function and discriminant of a quadratic equation. Also I couldn't get what you mean in the first line of comment 'the function here being a polynomial and a quadratic polynomial at that.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to determine which the numbers $y$ such that the equation $x^2+6x-1=y$, which is equivalent to $x^2+6x-1-y=0$. But this quadratic equation has solutions if and only if $6^2+4(1+y)\ge0$, and
$$
6^2+4(1+y)\ge0\iff1+y\ge-9\iff y\ge-10.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, one way to find the range is to complete the square.
\begin{align*} 
f(x) & = x^2 + 6x - 1\\
     & = (x^2 + 6x) - 1\\
     & = (x^2 + 6x + 9) - 9 - 1\\
     & = (x + 3)^2 - 10
\end{align*}
which is the equation of a parabola with vertex $(-3, -10)$ that opens upwards.  Hence, the range of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2 + 6x - 1$ is $[-10, \infty)$.

If $y$ is in the range of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2 + 6x - 1$
then it must satisfy the quadratic equation
$$x^2 + 6x - 1 = y$$
or, equivalently,
$$x^2 + 6x - 1 - y = 0$$
We know that a quadratic equation has real roots if its discriminant is nonnegative.  In this case, the discriminant is
\begin{align*}
\Delta & = b^2 - 4ac\\
       & = 6^2 - 4(1)(-1 - y)\\
       & = 36 + 4 + 4y\\
       & = 40 + 4y
\end{align*}
Hence, $y$ is in the range of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ if
\begin{align*}
\Delta & \geq 0\\
40 + 4y & \geq 0\\
4y & \geq -40\\
y & \geq -10
\end{align*}